# Why Java 7 release not available after jdk-7u80?

Tags: java, java-7

I want to download `JRE 1.7.0_131-b31` as i read its support `TLSv1.2` by default

> TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.1 are now enabled by default on the TLS client
> end-points. This is similar behavior to what already happens in JDK 8
> releases.

But Oracle site showing latest version of [jdk-7u80](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase7-archive-downloads.html) and after this release no other Java 7 version available.

1. Is this because ,user have to buy license/paid version ?
2. These version not available for individual developer ?

Comment: Why not Java 8 or any later version which support tls 1.2 by defqult?

Comment: @NomadMaker Few restriction from Client side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why Java 7 release not available after jdk-7u80?

Because of Oracle business reasons.  Free public support ended in April 2015.

(Backporting patches and so on requires a team of people.  That costs money.  Oracle is a commercial enterprise.   And other reasons.)

> Is this because user have to buy license/paid version ?

Yes.  You need an Extended Support Contract to use versions after 7u80

> These version not available for individual developer ?

No.

If you or your client requires Java 7 with TLSv1.1 and later, your options are:

1. Upgrade to Java 8 or (better) 11. This is the best option.
2. Use a 3rd-party JCE provider (such as BouncyCastle) that still supports Java 7.
3. Pay Oracle for an "Extended Support" support contract.

Point out to the client that this is the cost of them not investing the money / effort in keeping their Java application stack up with the latest versions.

If they are still using old libraries and applications that are permanently stuck at Java 7, they should be planning to discard or replace them.  Yes it is painful, but it is more painful in the long term if they don't.  (In July 2022, even "Extended Support" ends for Java 7.  After that, even security fixes will stop.)

Note that Java 8 is due to reach end of life fairly soon too.  Indeed, free support for commercial use has already ceased for Oracle Java 8.  You / they should really be aiming to get to Java 11 ASAP.

I would also suggest that if they want you to continue supporting them on Java 7, they should be (in effect) paying for the Java support contract that you need to do your job.  Renegotiate your billing rate, or whatever.

For more information on Java versions, end of life, and end of support; see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history
- https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html

Comment: Although some ancient code did things like explicitly set URLConnection to use com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactory -- if so, that kills #2.